# Android: Selecting a song from a drop-down menu and playing the song with MediaPlayer

Tags: android

Is there a way to select a song from a drop-down and play using Media Player?

Right now I use:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
```

in the initViews() method.

What I need to know is could I do something like this:

```
if spinner.getselectedItem().toString().equals("song1"){
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
} else{
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song2);
```

Code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

private Button buttonPlayStop;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SeekBar seekBar;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

// Here i override onCreate method.
//
// setContentView() method set the layout that you will see then
// the application will starts
//
// initViews() method i create to init views components.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
}

// This method set the setOnClickListener and method for it (buttonClick())
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void initViews() {
    buttonPlayStop = findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
    buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {@Override public void onClick(View v) {buttonClick();}});

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("song1")){
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
    } else {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song2);
    }

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
    categories.add("song1");
    categories.add("song2");

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);

    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        seekChange(v);
        return false; }
    });
}

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
    }else{
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
    }
}

// This is event handler thumb moving event
private void seekChange(View v){
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
    }
}

// This is event handler for buttonClick event
private void buttonClick(){
    if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
        try{
            mediaPlayer.start();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            startPlayProgressUpdater();
        }catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        }
    }else {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: if you accept my answer I'll upvote you :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onItemSelected` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "Selected: " +item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (item.equals("song1")){
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1);
    } else {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added in the following code, however seeming to get a null pointer in the buttonClick() method - line mediaPlayer.start(); Looks to me that mediaPlayer is initialized correctly? Thoughts?

Comment: it's not related to your current question, so accept my answer and then post your new question in another post :)